# Can you do a $json = file_get_contents($url); within a foreach statment already using $json = file_get_contents($url);?

Tags: php, foreach, file-get-contents

```
$url = "www.test.com"
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach($data as $mydata) {

    $id = $mydata->id;

        $url2 = "www.test.com/$id";
        $json2 = file_get_contents($url2);
        $data2 = json_decode($json2);
        var_dump($data2); // seems to always be null?? :(

            foreach($data2 as $mydata2) {

                   .............
                }
}
```

the error I get is Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() which is because data2 is not an array....

Guessing I can't do file_get_contents() stacked like I am. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You can use it, the question is, what is returned from the second URL. Is it valid JSON?

Comment: I asked my question too soon. Found my error. I was going to the wrong url. It was returning XML and not JSON.

Comment: you missed `http://` protocol at the beginning of the URL

Answer (score -2, accepted):

URL isn't returning valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

First check, is your url return a JSON? If yes then you can use following instead

```
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

The TRUE returns an array instead of an object.